# Want to change this code to write in excel using python3?

Tags: python, excel, csv

> How to convert this code to get output in excel?

```
with open('table.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for table in extracted_document['tables']:
         for row in table['rows']:
             wr.writerow([cell['content'] for cell in row['cells']])
```

> I am using this code to get output in cvs file but now i want to write in excel..how to change this code to get output in excel? please help me

Comment: have you tried looking here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xlwt module.

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
for table in extracted_document['tables']:
    for row_cnt, row in enumerate(table['rows']):
        for col_cnt, c in enumerate([cell['content'] for cell in row['cells']]):
            ws.write(row_cnt, col_cnt, c)
wb.save('table.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

'''
**Create workbook**
'''

```
import xlwt
workbook=xlwt.Workbook()
sheet=workbook.add_sheet("Sheet Name")
```

'''
**write to cell**
'''

```
sheet.write(0,0,'foobar')#row ,column,value
```

'''
**use style**
'''

```
stype=xlwt.easyxf('font:bold 1')
sheet.write(0,0,'foobar',style)
```

'''